# Selecting an element whose ID has a period in it

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have an element that has a period in it:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="my.element"></div>
</div>
```

and I want to select it using Prototype. I've tried this:

```
$$('#parent #my.element');
```

but it isn't working because it thinks the `.element` part is a class. Is there a way around this?

FYI, it isn't really an option to rename the element. Unfortunately I'm stuck with this naming scheme as well as only Prototype

Thanks

Comment: See [Can't select div with id=“:1”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28062010/1529630), but using `.` instead of `:`

Comment: you could use target based on the id starting with 'my'.  this would only work if you don't have other divs with id starting with 'my'.  `$("div[id^='my']")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always [escape](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) your dot in css, so this should work

```
$$('#parent #my\\.element');
```

EDIT: As stated by Oriol and tested, you indeed have to use 2 slashes

Comment: This won't work. The slash will escape the dot in the string literal, so the resulting string won't have the slash. You need to escape the slash with another one.